# Expand navigation menu by clicking item name in Oracle Apex 5

Tags: javascript, html, css, oracle-apex-5

Currently menu items expanded by clicking on arrow at right side. But I want to expand the list by clicking the item name. For example, in below image, I need to expand/collapse list by clicking on **Settings** instead of clicking on marked arrow head.

[image: nav_bar]

Comment: More information needed, a code sample could help

Comment: @Senthilnathan I am using apex-5 Universal Theme

Comment: Please go through the [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) section and improve your question.

Answer (score 1):

By default, it's only possible to expand the side navigation menu children submenu by clicking on the corresponding down arrow.

Maxime Tremblay described a [solution](http://max-tremblay.blogspot.de/2016/01/accordion-like-navigation-menu.html) and a [demo](http://max-playground.no-ip.org/ords/f?p=DEMO:1000).